# Integrate Angular application to saml

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, saml

Hi I am new to angular and even saml as well, I have started building angular 6 application, I wanted to integrate the application with saml so that I can work on login module using VIDM. I am not sure how to achieve this. Can anybody tell me how can this be achieved? Basically I want to integrate my application to saml first.

Comment: Let us know what effort you put into. I would recommend you to google it and ask question on more specific topic

Comment: Hi I have been searching through google, and I am not getting proper solution or document related to this.

Answer (score 0):

You need a client side [SAML stack](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43).

Or look at an Identity as a Service offering e.g. Auth0, Okta etc.

Comment: I have an app where frontend is angular and backend is in Java. So I am wondering if saml2js can be used with angularjs?

Comment: SAML is a protocol and is language agnostic. So if your IDP requires SAML then use saml2js.

Comment: Would you help with SO question I've added, it has more detailed description https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53957569/saml-with-adfs-for-angularjsjavajetty-webapp