# SAML with ADFS for angularjs+java+jetty webapp

Tags: angularjs, rest, jetty, saml-2.0, restlet

I am working on a webapp, the Front-end is implemented in AngularJS which talks to back-end server by invoking REST API. The back-end is Java REST Server implemented using [reslet framework](https://restlet.com/) deployed in Jetty.

Currently, when a user logs into a web app, a REST API is invoked which then goes to the Java REST server. The server then authenticates the user.

I want to implement SSO using SAML. So when a corporate user tries to login to the app, the user must be redirected to ADFS. If the user is successfully authenticated he must be allowed to login to the app.

I want to know how do I start? I have seen sam2-js library, however it seems to be for NodeJS based server. I am not quite sure if it can be used with AngularJS on frontend.

Comment: "Where do I start..." style questions tend to be overly broad and very difficult to answer.  One thing that is certain, however, is that you are focusing in the wrong place here; This isn't something angularjs can be responsible for at all.  Your authentication is being handled in Jetty, so it should be responsible for figuring out if the user has access through SAML.  Angularjs shouldn't care at all about who the user is or how they need to authenticate.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out in the right direction. Do you think pac4j or keycloak could be a good candidate to begin with?

Comment: @claies would you share your thoughts on the below answer?

Comment: it feels like this just exposes a bit more that the whole process needs to be fleshed out a bit more.  How do users currently log in to the REST API without SAML?  I don't see how "Jetty is Irrelevant", since it is a key piece in the SAML flow.

Comment: a Typical SAML flow follows:  1) The user accesses the remote application (your Jetty Instance) using a link on an intranet.  2) The application identifies the user’s origin and redirects the user back to the identity provider (your ADFS).  3) The identity provider builds the authentication response in the form of an XML-document containing the user’s username or email address, signs it using an X.509 certificate, and posts this information to the application. 4) The application, which already knows the identity provider, retrieves the authentication response and validates it.

Comment: As you can see, none of this could be done through a client app.

Answer (score 0):

SSO with SAML involves browser redirects so the flow is between angular and ADFS.

There's no Java backend.

So Jetty is irrelevant.

SSO has nothing to do with REST. They are two different flows handled in two different ways.

SAML is not a suitable SSO protocol for angular. That's why you can't find any examples.

You need to use OpenID Connect with ADFS 4.0. [ADAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/ad-fs-development) is the way to go.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why Jetty is irrelevant. My backend is implemented in Java using Restlet framework.

Comment: SSO is user based between a browser or a device and an IDP. This result of this is an access token (if using OIDC). The access token can be passed to an API to authenticate. But the API flow is not SSO.

Comment: Ok. Can you help me understand why is SAML not suitable for Angular JS? I've been asked to try to implement SSO with SAML for non technical reasons.

Comment: The only SAML js implementation I know of is Passport (node.js). SAML is cryptographically heavy and being js and client side keeping keys secure is problematic. Also XML SAML tokens cannot be used as API JWT tokens. Use OIDC. It's simpler and produces JWT access tokens.

Comment: SAML is mainly used these days for enterprise i.e. company to company. It has an SSO profile but doesn't really have a profile suitable for native i.e. mobile, desktop, command line.